# Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Event[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I am getting the following error when I try to fetch the items:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Event[]>'.
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': code, name, password, pollCat
```

`events.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Event } from '../models/events'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

  eventsCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Event>;
  events : Observable<Event[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.events = this.afs.collection('Events').valueChanges();
  }

  getEvents()
  {
    return this.events;
  }
}
```

`events.ts`:

```
export interface Event{

    code: string;
    name: string;
    password: string;
    pollCat : string;

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to supply the generic type when calling the `collection` method, rather than using the default `unknown`:

```
this.events = this.afs.collection<Event>('Events').valueChanges();
                              // ^ here
```

You can read more about generics in the TypeScript handbook [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Comment: @AkshatMehrotra no problem, FYI see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Another doubt sir, I am getting this int the console Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EventsService: (?), even when all four properties in my database are string and I have assigned parameters according to that in the interface. What should I do?\

Comment: @AkshatMehrotra please take the [tour] and review [ask] - if you have another question, *once you've thoroughly researched the issue yourself and tried hard to solve it*, ask it separately. Given that the unresolved parameter is `AngularFirestore` I'd guess you haven't included the module correctly, maybe re-read their docs for how to install and use that library.